# Regular Expression (Replace) only first match

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to cut (replace) a string with regular Expression (sed) but want to match the **first** occurence. In Result you can see it stops ever at the third DATA.

Text:

```
Cool Text Cool Text DATA : first text DATA : second text DATA : third text
```

Regular Expression:

```
sed 's/.*DATA//'
```

Result:

```
 : third text
```

Comment: Result is of course ": third text"

Comment: Why you don't use grep to take what you want?

Comment: How to do this? Grep can Replace or Cut a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed, you can use the trick of the placeholder:

```
sed  's/DATA/###/;s/.*###//;'
```

With gnu grep, you can use a lookbehind in perl mode:

```
grep -Po '(?<=DATA).*'
```

Comment: too bad `sed` doesn't support lookarounds.. Can you explain about the placeholder trick?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: sed makes two replacements, first it replace the first `DATA` with `###` (or anything you want that is not in the string), and then it makes a second replacement to remove all until the "unique" placeholder. With this way you don't care if the quantifier is greedy or not, since the placeholder is unique.

Comment: @hek2mgl: T{anks} `+``1`

Comment: grep can also be used with OR `grep -Po '(?<=SOMETHING|DATA).*'`

Comment: Thank you for the fast Solution :-)

Comment: assuming there is no `###` in the string (like your sample show but seems to be *generic*)

Comment: +1. FYI the way to create and use a placeholder string that's guaranteed to not exist in the input is this: `sed 's/a/aA/g; s/DATA/aB/; s/.*aB//; s/aA/a/g' file`. The first substitution puts an `A` after every `a` so that afterwards `aB` (or `a` followed by `anything-but-A`) cannot exist in the input. The second replaces the first `DATA` with `aB`. The 3rd removes everything up to `aB`. The 4th changes all the `aA`s back to `a`s. I've found that to be an extremely useful idiom to know over the years.

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to perl, you can use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
echo "$string" | perl -pe 's/.*?DATA//'
# .............................^
```

That will stop at the *first* DATA

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/DATA\(.*\)/&#\1/;s/.*DATA\(.*\)#\1/\1/' YourFile
```

Sed always try to take the biggest pattern, so in your problem, it take all until last DATA (biggest possible). I just use the reverse construction by *keeping* the biggest.

Comment: Why not, but this doesn't remove characters before "DATA".

Comment: oops, you are right, i have to change a bit :-( sorry